# Create object property with javascript variable content (and work on safari)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a javascript object with a property that's a declared string:

```
var theTitle = 'Hello';
helloWorld = {theTitle : 'World'};
```

Will output 'theTitle' as the property name..

So I tried:

```
var theTitle = 'Hello';
helloWorld = {[theTitle] : 'World'};
```

Works well, but not on Safari..

What's the way to do this??

Comment: Use a transpiler if you want ES6 to work in older browsers.

Comment: create your empty object first `helloWorld = {};`  Then `add` the fields to it ...